# Create Pouchdb txt file for offline app

Tags: pouchdb

I want to create pouchdb dump from chrome database in Windows 7. How will we do it? I know about pouchdb-dump-cli but I cannot create a txt file out of the pouchdb database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pouchdb-dump-cli is typically used to dump a *CouchDB* database. So the easiest way to dump from Chrome is:

1. Replicate from Chrome (IndexedDB) to a CouchDB database. This is as simple as `localDB.replicate.to('http://localhost:5984/mydatabase')`.
2. Dump that CouchDB database using `pouchdb-dump-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some coffeescript to create a zipped dump of pouchdb data that will be 'downloaded' from within the browser:

```
  dumpedString = ''
  stream = new window.memorystream()
  stream.on 'data', (chunk) ->
    dumpedString += chunk.toString()

  database.dump(stream).then ->
    zip = new JSZip()
    zip.file "backup.pouchdb", dumpedString
    saveAs(zip.generate(type:"blob",compression:"DEFLATE"), "backup.pouchdb.zip")
  .catch (error) -> console.error error
```

(it depends on a few libraries: JSZIP, saveAs, memorystream and most importantly: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream)